# Linear Transformation Test

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey can some help me with this textbook question I think it is a linear transformation I just want to be sure thanks

Let $T : P_2 \rightarrow P_2$ be dened by

$T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2}) = (a_0 - a_1 - a_2) + (a_1 + a_2)x$

Either show that T is a linear transformation, or explain why it is not a linear
transformation.

Comment: If you show me your proof of why you think it's a linear transformation, I'll confirm its correctness. (but throw me an `@mixedmath` tag if you do)

Comment: @mixedmath cause it holds true for $T(u) + T(v) = T(u + v)$ and $cT(u) = T(cu)$ i just what to be sure I am right thanks

Comment: Yes, we need to check that $T(u)+T(v)=T(u+v)$ and $cT(u)=T(cu)$ both hold.  If you've shown this is true (and it really should be just a matter of using the definition), then you've shown it's a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

T maps $(a_0,a_1,a_2)^T$ to $(a_0-a_1-a_2,a_1+a_2,0)^T$, which is an operation represented by the matrix
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So that $T((a_0,a_1,a_2)):=M\cdot(a_0,a_1,a_2)^T=(a_0-a_1-a_2,a_1+a_2,0)^T$

Therefore the operation is linear.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that $T$ is a [linear transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map), we need to check that addition and scalar multiplication is preserved by $T$.

So we need to check that $$T((a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2}) + (b_0 + b_1 x + b_2x^{2})) = T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2}) + T(b_0 + b_1 x + b_2x^{2})$$ and $$T(\lambda(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2})) = \lambda\ T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2})$$ for all $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^{2},b_0 + b_1 x + b_2x^{2} \in P_2$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (or whatever scalar field is in use).